# flann python bindings

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, perhaps i've got things wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to get flann to work with python.

I'm using diamondback on ubuntu 10.10. I noticed that the python path export in the flann package manifest (and in the trunk versions in the pcl svn) were commented out and wrong. Upon adding the correct path it seems to work fine.

Can someone point me at a howto for bug reports/patch, or maybe tell me which package I should be using?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9856/flann-python-bindings/) by [Sandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/377/sandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd be interested in this - it seems that python bindings for flann and a few other packages (can't remember off the top of my head) seem to come and go randomly, meaning our systems work, then there is an update and all python support disappears, then sometime later it all comes back.

---

Originally posted by [Nick H](https://answers.ros.org/users/152/nick-h/) with karma: 214 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/377/sandy/) on 2011-05-24**:
In order to fix it I had to uncomment and fix the line in the manifest for the python path. Unfortunately, with flann it's not as simple as including a .so file in the binary release. (It's somewhere inside the build directory, it's in the flann manual under how to run in python)